# Jquery and Google Tag Manager

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I am having some problems implementing Google Tag Manager on my website. I have a Google code, and when I try it on my site, it makes **a lot** of javascript conflicts.

So I tried to put the code on a seperate file, in order to do it Step by Step and observe the behavior of the different scripts.

So here my very simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titre</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dataLayer = [{'uid':'12'}];
        (function(w,d,s,l,i){
            w[l]=w[l]||[];
            w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
            var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
            j.async=true;
            j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    hello
</body>
</html>
```

And this very page, returns an error in the JS console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Well, this is unexpected, what does jQuery has to do here? I didn't even declare it on my body tag, is Google requiring jQuery?

So that was weird, and the second thing, when I look on my generated HTML page, after loading on a browser:

```
<body>
... Long stuff here
<script type="text/javascript" id="" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
... some other stuff here
</body>
```

What kind of sorcery is this? Why does Google add a jquery thing at the bottom of my page, and why does my console shows me a jQuery error?

Thanks a lot for any kind of information, I am totally lost...
And have a nice day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the solution, as it says in an other question, jQuery was injected by the googletagmanager and it was configured by the Web Agency that configured the google tag manager.

So if you have the same problem, call your Web Agency...

And if you have configured yourself the tag manager, check in your settings on Google Tag Manager interface.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue where GTM has included v1.9.1 jQuery and my Wordpress site uses v1.11.3. I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". I'd say it's a conflict of jQuery libs. Is it possible to change the version of jQuery that GTM calls?

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs: GTM does not do shit in itself. It is the guy that configured it to inject custom HTML you need to talk to.

Answer (score 5):

Simo Ahava on the Google Tag Manager forums answered this type of question:

[Why jQuery might not be defined](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/tag-manager/IA5K0kCXerE/Wex4XgZGBwAJ)

Basically, he says that GTM does not load jQuery by default.

Even if your page does load it, the GTM tag that uses it might get triggered prior to the on page loading of jQuery.

You can either make your jQuery code wait for the library to be loaded or load it within the custom HTML tag.

Answer (score 2):

Like it has been said before, GTM might load before the page's jQuery loads. That means that if you use jQuery in the script injected via GTM, it might generate a "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", depending on the browser resource loading strategy.

That said, you must guarantee jQuery is loaded **before** the GTM script. You can do this by either:

1. controlling the order of loading of scripts
2. employing a hack such as using a `setInterval` loop until jQUery is available:

```js
var func = function() {
    if (jQuery) {  
        clearInterval(timer);
        // do your stuff
    }
}
var timer = setInterval(func, 1000);
```