# Do I need jQuery for Google Tag Manager to work? Using it with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-tag-manager, angulartics

I can't seem to find any answers on this.  I've got an AngularJs application, which I do not need jQuery for.  I've added Google Tag Manager using Angulartics but I'm getting a 'jQuery is not defined' error in the console.  Do I need to include jQuery just for GTM?  Since jQuery is no longer so much of a standard this surprises me?  And it's vaguely annoying!  Anyone know a way around it or can I just ignore the error and everything will work anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need jQuery.

The only relation between jQuery and GTM that I know of is that the code of the built-in selector engine so much resembled jQuery that Google agreed to add a jQuery copyright notice (at least that is what Simo Ahava told in one of his GTM trainings, and he is a Google Certified Expert for GTM, so I guess he has more insights than us).

But GTM does not require jQuery to work (that's sort of the point of having a built-in selector engine), and if you are seeing jQuery-related errors they come from a tag inside GTM that requires jQuery than from GTM itself (or, if you load marketing tags, they might in turn load something else that requires jQuery).

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  The client has control of the GTM account so I've not logged in to see what they've set up - but I can't imagine they've done anything particularly technical.  I'm not sure how they can have done something that requires jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of [Jquery and Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755168/jquery-and-google-tag-manager)

the answer might be here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/IA5K0kCXerE

Comment: I dont think so - this answers how to get jquery working.  I'm trying to find out if I can avoid using it altogether, since I don't need it.  Also these posts are years old so I'm hoping that there might be a more up to date answer?  Thanks though