# How not to use jQuery with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-tag-manager

When I implement the Google Tag Manager in the header of my website, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

How do I get rid of that error without implementing jQuery? GTM is referencing an (online stored) js file which, as it seems, relies upon jQuery and throws that error.

What I have found online is that GTM works without it as well, but having an error in the console is unacceptable for this project. How do I install GTM without jQuery nor this error throw? I am using Angular.

This is the output of the console:

```
VM2454:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:135
at gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:974
at Object.c [as __html] (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:976)
at tb (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:835)
at e (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:879)
at gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:827
at Array.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:880)
at Object.Qf (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:879)
at Ce (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:880)
at Ee (gtm.js?id=GTM-XX:882)
```

From what I read by now, I think some Tags are depending on jQuery and I have to either disable all those tags or implement jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755168/jquery-and-google-tag-manager

Comment: I already read this thread but it did not show me what I can change to make the error disappear.

Comment: Can you edit your post with example code usage?

Comment: I did, do you need the gtm.js file aswell? I am a bit concerned that this could contain confidential Data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery and Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755168/jquery-and-google-tag-manager)

Answer (score 0):

What's likely is that someone who has access to your GTM container put in custom script in there that relies on jQuery, GTM container does not use jQuery at all.

What you need to do is go into the GTM container and look for all the "custom html" tags and figure out why they need jQuery and go from there.